# Deploying to App Service Environment from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We have 1 **internal** ASE in a subnet. In a different subnet in the same network, we have deployed a Virtual Machine that acts as `Azure DevOps Agent Windows v2`

We are able to deploy Web Apps manually (using Visual Studio) from a machine that access to this Virtual Network, but cant get deployment working from Azure DevOps.

Here's what we have done

- Default NSG rules exist so traffic is enabled on 80/443 ports. Updated NSG to allow traffic to/from: `13.107.6.183` and `13.107.9.183` (checked with all ports)
- Pipeline Task added flag `-allowUntrusted`

The error we get during deployment is:

```
More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("{myapp}.scm.{customdomain}.com"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
Error: Unable to connect to the remote server
Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx:443
Error count: 1.
```

Are we missing anything in NSG rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internet-based CI systems, such as GitHub and Azure DevOps, will still work with an ILB ASE if the build agent is internet accessible and on the same network as ILB ASE. So in case of Azure DevOps, if the build agent is created on the same VNET as ILB ASE (different subnet is fine), it will be able to pull code from Azure DevOps git and deploy to ILB ASE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase

You can also follow the detailed steps in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/01/04/continuous-deployment-with-vststfs-and-app-service-environment-ase/) article

Hope this helps!

Comment: All of the above is true. The CI Agent is Internet accessible, in same network as ILB ASE, the `hosts` file on Agent has entries to map ILB IP to ASE urls (ASE + SCM) for each Web App. But still getting this error

Comment: Can you try tcpping to the VM from webapp's Kudu console and check if that succeeds?

Comment: Solved this. There were 2 NSGs - one on `Agent VM subnet` and other on `ASE subnet`. Traffic on `Port 80/443` should be allowed